# On plotting in HTML5 slides with knitr

Tags: html, r, knitr, ggplot2

Here is my problematic slide:

[image]

The plain text for this slide is

````
# Title
```{r plot, echo=FALSE}
library("ggplot2")
x <- seq(-1,1,0.05)
y <- x^3/3-x^2 + rnorm(41,sd=0.1)
qplot(x,y)+geom_smooth()
```
- item 1
- item 2
````

And I want to：

1. Hide the comment text (## blahblah)
2. Hide the text "plot of chunk plot"
3. Make the plot smaller, so that the items can be shown

Could you please give me some hints? Thank you.

Comment: Read [the wonderful documentation for knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/options). You need to look at `fig.cap`, `warning` and `fig.height` and `fig.width

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should take time to read the wonderful documentation provided for [`knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/options).

Without knowing your work flow to create the slides it is hard answer from the html5 end.

You are looking for `fig.width`, `fig.height`, `fig.cap`, `warning` and `message` from the `knitr` chunk options.

````
```{r plot, echo=FALSE,fig.width = 3, fig.height = 3,  fig.cap = '', warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, cache = FALSE}
library("ggplot2")
x <- seq(-1,1,0.05)
y <- x^3/3-x^2 + rnorm(41,sd=0.1)
qplot(x,y)+geom_smooth()
```
- item 1
- item 2
````

You will have to adjust the height and width to get the size that is suitable for slides

Comment: If you make your question reproducible with your html5 workflow. My answer works with my pandoc approach.

Comment: OK now, should be `out.width` and `out.height`. Thanks for you hints.

Comment: weird, I am using pandoc too.